# Run-time error 1004 when trying to select OLAP pivotfield array element

Tags: excel, vba, loops, powerpivot

I'm having trouble looping through the items in my OLAP pivot field. I have an array which contains the names/items I want the filter to loop through, but I cannot get the pivot field to select an array element (I want only one selected at a time)

There are many questions out there with similar problems out there, like [this](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?56582-VBA-amp-OLAP-Pivot-Code-to-set-report-filter-pvt-field-with-items-from-another-pvt-tabl)
 and [this](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/621374-filter-olap-pivot-table-based-named-range-another-worksheet.html), and I have tried to incorporate the coding to my code. However I can't seem to get it to work for me

This is my code at the moment. I have tried using currentpage rather than visibleitemlist, and instead of element just use i or industryarray(i).

```
Sub Test()

Dim IndustryArray() As Variant
Dim element As Variant

Dim Industry As Range
Dim Data As Variant

Dim ptITS As PivotTable
Dim pfITS As PivotField
Dim ppfITS As PivotField

Set ptITS = Worksheets("Industry Time Series").PivotTables("PivotTable1")
Set pfITS = ptITS.PivotFields("[All Industries Combined].[Industry Details].[Industry Details]")
Set ppfITS = ptITS.PageFields("[All Industries Combined].[Industry Details].[Industry Details]")

Set Industry = Worksheets("Industry List").Range("A2:A211")
ReDim IndustryArray(0 To Industry.Cells.Count + 1)

For i = 0 To Industry.Cells.Count + 1
    IndustryArray(i) = "[ All Industries Combined].[Industry Details].&[" & Industry.Cells(i + 1).Value & "]"
Next i

For Each element In IndustryArray
    pfITS.ClearAllFilters
    pfITS.VisibleItemsList = element <-- error (for different variations as well)
Next element

End Sub
```

I want the filter to select each item of the array, then clear filter and move to the next item. Just get errors at the identified line.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

While I don’t have a VBA example I hope [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OlapPivotTableExtensions/OlapPivotTableExtensions/master/OlapPivotTableExtensions/MainForm.cs) C# code will help you find the problem in your code. Look for the `workerFilterList_DoWork` method. The relevant code is:

```
            Excel.CubeField field = pvt.CubeFields.get_Item(args.LookIn);
            field.CreatePivotFields();
            field.IncludeNewItemsInFilter = false; //if this is set to true, they essentially wanted to show everything but what was specifically unchecked. With Filter List, we're doing the reverse... showing only what's spefically checked

            foreach (string sLevelUniqueName in dictLevelsOfFoundMembers.Keys)
            {
                Excel.PivotField pivotField = (Excel.PivotField)field.PivotFields.Item(sLevelUniqueName);
                if (field.Orientation == Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlPageField)
                {
                    field.EnableMultiplePageItems = true;
                }
                System.Array arrNewVisibleItems = dictLevelsOfFoundMembers[sLevelUniqueName].ToArray();
                pivotField.VisibleItemsList = arrNewVisibleItems;
                if (field.Orientation == Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlHidden)
                {
                    field.Orientation = Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlRowField; //if it's not in the PivotTable, then add it to rows
                }
                pivotField.ClearValueFilters();
                pivotField.ClearLabelFilters();
            }
```

Comment: Hey Greg, sorry for the late response. I must say that I am very unfamiliar with C#, and am still learning Excel VBA. I generally understand the logic you are using (I think), but I am having trouble translating it to VBA.